# How to change two records filed value in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my project for showing Grid data, I order by priority and user can change record Priority by arrow (down,up).
For Change Priority I use this code:

```
    public virtual JsonResult ChangeOrder(int selectedCode, bool isUp)
    {

        var NewsObj = _newsService.Get(selectedCode);
        if (NewsObj == null)
            return Json(new { result = false, message = "error" });

        int CurrentPriority = NewsObj.Priority;

        int OtherPriority = 0;

        if (isUp)
        {
            OtherPriority = CurrentPriority - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            OtherPriority = CurrentPriority + 1;
        }

        var OtherNews = _newsService.GetByPriority(OtherPriority);
        if (OtherNews == null)
            return Json(new { result = false, message = "error" });

        int tmp = NewsObj.Priority;
        NewsObj.Priority = OtherNews.Priority;
        OtherNews.Priority = tmp;
        _uow.MarkAllAsChanges(NewsObj);
        _uow.MarkAllAsChanges(OtherNews);
        _uow.SaveAllChanges();

        return Json(new { result = true, message = "success" });
    }
```

But this codes depends on ordering, for example when I use `OrdeyByDesc` this row does not work because `--` and `++` should change.
I want to be independent of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mix the meaning or Priority and Ordering.

Priority is normally not giving an order, because two or more elements can have the same Priority. It's giving only a kind of demand for this element.

An Order instead is lining up the elements in a sequence, so that each element has an unique Order Position. This can be done by using the Priority and/or other fields, may be something like a timestamp. Also it can be done ascendant or descendant, but that will not change the Priority.

So I would suggest to implement a functionality for changing the Priority. And separate, implement a second functionality for ordering, that can include an OrderByPriority. If someone changes the Priority of an element, just refresh the ordered list and the element will go up or down or wherever...